# Is player prefs saving values slow?

Tags: c#, android, performance, unity-game-engine

I found some answers about this but they vary from age to age (last one 2015) so i was wondering about this because i need it so to know how to build my code. I have leveling system with experience and let's say player can get from 1 to 10-15 times xp in one sec (let's say he use AOE spell and kill 15 mobs) so i want to know what is better approach:

- Every time player gains XP it saves it directly with `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat()` so it can happen that it will activate `SetFloat` 15 times in one moment
- Load player xp inside code on game start, than to do all calculations inside code and at the game close i save that to PlayerPrefs.

I would like to use first approach since for me it is much safer but i do not know if that would be slow.

Comment: `PlayerPrefs` are slow and you should use them to persist some data from scene to scene or from the start of your application untill it's closed. You can use it to store some configurations, settings etc. but I would suggest to not use it to store sensitive user data ( such as highscores, experience, points etc. )

Comment: You don't save data 15x per sec. You only save data when you are about to load new scene, when game ends and new one is about to restart, when you exit the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PlayerPrefs is generally better suited for saving player-specific options such as volume or screen-size, or small game-applications. Once your game gets larger and more complex, you could consider creating XML, TXT, or some kind of other file to save your game data.

You can take a look at [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-do-you-store-game-data-damage-spell-data-etc.67332/) discussion on the Unity Forum.

Additionally, auto-saving 15 times per second is a bad idea in general, since it's pretty pointless. If you really implement auto-saving, you should consider increasing the delay between the saving, or save upon scene-change or some other event that is not called way too frequently.

Comment: Every saving i have done is to playerprefs (Exp, Level, Name, Inventory, Stats...). What i am scared is that if i save it to TXT file it will be easy accessible and everyone would be able to change it. Is there anything safer?

Comment: @AleksaRistic There are a various number of methods to encrypt save data, or you can write your own encryption algorithm. There is also a discussion on this on the [Unity forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/encrypting-save-files-etc.190789/).

Comment: Ok. One more question. Could i possibly save files to my ftp?

Comment: Basically you do not have to encrypt any data to store it in file. You can just come up with some serialization method and (re)store that serialized data. Forcing everything on to the ftp is possible but it's also not a good idea for the single player game.

Comment: @AleksaRistic I don't see why not, take a look at [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1146668/ftp-upload-files.html).

Comment: Thank you guys so much. I would like game to be multiplayer but i am afraid that i am not capable of doing it right now so i am checking for all possibilities and when i am ready i will try to make it multiplayer. Thanks again you are awesome!

Comment: @AleksaRistic I'd be careful when deciding to code a multiplayer game, it gets extremely complicated pretty fast. If you decide to so anyway, Unity has some pretty good learning sessions on it and there is also enough other information on the internet on how to do so. Good luck!